# Any PHP class that produces local time for a particular city of the world respecting DST changes?

Tags: php

Is there a PHP(-MySQL) script (/class) that produces local time for a particular city of the world respecting DST changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `DateTime` object representing the local time for any valid ISO-3166-1 timezone identifier.

```
$bigAppleTime = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("America/New_York"));
echo "It is currently " . $bigAppleTime->format('r') . " in New York city";
```

You can get a list of valid identifiers and the current time at each by doing the following:

```
$timezones = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers();

foreach($timezones as $zone) {
  $time = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($zone));
  printf("% 35s: %s\n", $zone, $time->format('r'));
}
```